# Angular 7 Tabs in component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Need to create a component having say - 2 tabs
on click of each tab need to redirect to specific component.

for ex - say i have two tabs on a single page - Tab 1, Tab 2
on click of Tab 1 need to see Component_1
on click of Tab 2 need to see Component_2

To be clear UI something like- https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

but any way without using Angular material Tabs

Comment: if i correctly understood your question then please find the link https://stackblitz.com/angular/lklygoqrgao or else please elaborate your question ?

Comment: @rahullad - i wanted something like -https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) for that.

**module.ts**

```
import { CollapseModule, BsDropdownModule, AccordionModule, TabsModule, BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
 ]
})
```

**file.html**

```
<div class="tabs-resp-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['tab1']" routerLinkActive="active">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['tab2']" routerLinkActive="active">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am marking it as answer since it worked for me..
In addition to this how can i make tab look like selected when any tab is selected..

Answer (score 3):

Maintain a 'Tabs' array variable with property 'type' for each Object.
eg: `Tabs: any[] = [ {name:'Tab1', type:'tab1'} , {name:'Tab2', type:'tab2'}];`
Based on the 'type' property, load/Switch particular Tab's component in HTML.
eg:

```
<div *ngFor='let tab of Tabs' [ngSwitch]="tab.type">
     <tab1-comp *ngSwitchCase="'tab1'"></tab1-component>
     <tab2-comp *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'"></tab2-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a header component for it and define it on app component and after that start router navigation and give routing may it will help you out

`<header-component></header-component><router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to load Component_1 and Component_2 dynamically. Dynamic means, that the components location in the application is not defined at build time. That means, that it is not used in any angular template. Instead, the component is instantiated and placed in the application at runtime. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) how to dynamically create components in Angular7