# Tab component design in Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

As title says. I come from React background and found it was pretty easy to build a Tab component that receives an array of components and renders the certain component by the active tab index. Im unable to wrap my head around a similar design using Angular, would love someone to point me at the right direction. The idea is taken from React, and is as follows:

a Tab is defined as:

```
export interface Tab{
    title: string
    content: ReactNode
}
```

The consumer of this component provides an array of renderable content which can literaly be anything. So for example the consumer creates an array of "tabable" content:

```
  const tabData: Tab[] = [
    { title: 'First tab', content: 'some tab content' },
    { title: 'Second tab', content: ['1', 2, 3] },
    { title: 'Third tab', content: <FancyButton onClickAction={action} /> },
  ]
```

Then pass the array as a simple prop

```
<TabComponent tabs={tabData}/>
```

The TabComponent holds a simple numeric state of activeTabIndex, the render function simply calls the renderContent function that returns the active tab content, something like this:

```
render(
   {renderContent(tabs[activeTab].content)}
)
```

renderContent function looks something like this:

```
const renderContent = (content: ReactNode) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(content)) return content
    if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        return content.map((item, i: number) => {
            return <div key={i}>{ item }</div>
        })
    }
    return <div>{content}</div>
}
```

I do not know how to achieve the same effect using Angular. How do I render a component within a component, do I use `ng-content`, or `ComponentFactoryResolver`, or maybe `ngTemplateOutlet`? How do I define the type of the `@Input` of the TabComponent? How the rendered component interacts with its parent?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134736/angular-7-tabs-in-component) thread but i dont want to hardcode anything, I want to pass some content and the TabComponent will output it without knowing ahead of time the type of the data.

Comment: It’s great that you want to try Angular - but your questions are so basic that it might simply be best to first follow some tutorials? What you want is just as simple in Angular as it is in React (maybe even simpler in Angular).

Answer (score 0):

Without diving into too much detail and providing code examples I will say that the concept is fairly similar, you would define the tab objects and their associated components.

You can then implement loading the components using https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.